# How do you figure out the bottle necks in an AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

AngularJS batarang is unusable. It freezes and is unresponsive. How do you figure out where the bottlenecks are? What kind of tools can I use to profile my application to figure out if its my directives or if I have too many watchers?

Comment: I guess you have memory leaks. Have you tried chrome javascript memory profiler ?https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Answer (score 0):

This problem is perhaps caused, because you broke the watch-apply-digest cycle of the Angular framework by causing digest cycles where they should not be. This can cause Angular to create almost infinite loops watching variables for refresh, thus making your app really slow. But you can confirm that by just disabling Batarang, since the app would be slow by its own.

Anyway, if your app is efficient and only Batarang creates this issue, you can skip using it and start debugging with developer tools. I have also switched to this path various times and I can say it is quite fast (I did not expect it either). To follow this strategy, you have to simply select an element with developer tools and then execute in the JS console :

```
var scope = angular.element($0).scope()
```

So, you now have the scope of this element and you can simply check any field you want inside the scope at any time, thus testing the whole watch-apply-digest cycle of Angular.

You can learn more about the watch-apply-digest cycle [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Comment: What if it isn't slowing down overtime? It definitely gets faster as the data is loaded in.

Comment: You can try adding a promise tracker in your application to setup an animated icon during the loading of data (e.g. AJAX requests). In this way, you can see how much of the loading time is due to the fetching of data and how much is due to your implementation. Since the application gets faster as data is loaded in, I expect that the biggest bottleneck is data loading. In this case, you cannot make a lot of things to reduce this latency. However, you can design the application in a way that those requests are split over time in different stages, so that the user experience is improved.